# Do dask delayed functions use the same conda environment?

Tags: python, conda, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I've installed dask using conda. When I create delayed functions and run them over my PBS cluster using dask, how do I ensure that the worker nodes activate the same conda environment before running the delayed functions?

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/environment.html) gives you good general information about how imports and environments work across a dask cluster. In your PBS case, you may fall into the case where each workers see the same filesystem.

To configure the PBS launching, you should read [this](https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html), where you can define various settings, including the paths that the workers will be searching. *If* you also/instead have local storage on the nodes, then you might want to distribute environments using one of the methods in the first link.

Comment: You're right, I'm using a shared filesystem, so I don't need help distributing the files. However, I do need the workers to activate the conda environment upon startup before running the python code. What startup hook can I use to get them to do that? The PBS launching link you gave doesn't seem to describe any such hook.